# why converting my netcdf file to raster gives multi bands?

Tags: r

I have a netcdf file (temperature) and when I read/write it as a raster in R, it has many bands. How to get only one band? as it is only one value in the netcdf file.

```
                          points=108 (12x9)
                          lon : -16.5 to -11 by 0.5 degrees_east
                          lat : 12.5 to 16.5 by 0.5 degrees_north
```

sample data link:https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxz7194i1sjv3e2/sen_spei2era.nc?dl=0

Comment: Can you describe the dimensions of your data, and provide an example data set for us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Are you using `temperature <- stack("sen_spei2era.nc")` in `raster` package for reading the nc file? If so, `temperature` now is of class `RasterStack` and you can access the data of only one band (of class `RasterLayer`) by `$`.

Comment: I directly use tp

Comment: r<-raster(Test_ncdf, varname="spie")  ;  writeRaster(r, "era_spi", format = "GTiff", overwrite="True")

Comment: These are the command I use to read the file and write in tif. The lenght should only be 25, as it is yearly file. The raster is reading it as 8 bands where I expect only 1. I got the same with stack you used